# Is it possible to call a method from WinDbg / SOS

Tags: debugging, methods, call, windbg, sos

Is it possible to call managed method from windbg? Is there any .NET equivalent for `.call`? Or how to use it to call managed method?

I'm interested in attaching as a live session to a process on production (Release with no pdb) where is no possibility to use Visual Studio Debugger.

Comment: I don't know why you have two users, but if you want to edit your question, you should do it while logged as the user that originally created the question.