# WinDbg SoS execute .NET mehod (ToString)

Tags: .net, windbg, sos

I'd like to call a .NET method while debugging a .NET application with WinDbg / SoS.

The concrete issue is that the method `.ToString()` of an object generates relevant information for debugging. Obtaining this information manually can be tricky. So I'd like to call and obtain the results of a .NET method from WinDbg, in this case `.ToString`. I think that calling other methods can be useful too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of (unanswered) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151301/is-it-possible-to-call-a-method-from-windbg-sos

Comment: It's probably not so simple. `.call` can rely on a method that was already compiled. With .NET it may happen that the JIT compiler did not compile the IL code yet.

Comment: Within Visual Studio is very easy to add "Watches", or use the "Immediate Window", or "C# Interactive", etc, to see the result of a .NET method call. How could it be accomplished with WinDbg?

Comment: It's very hard in WinDbg. WinDbg was simply not made for .NET.